# Creating drop down menu and description changes

Tags: php, html, mysql, list

I currently have a web page that allows me to add businesses to a database with options of name, location, phone number and description.

Because I sometimes modify the description to be the same on several listings, I wanted to know how I can change my code in a way that I select several listings and add a description that will modify all selected in stead of having to modify each business individually.

This is my current code.

```
<?php include('includes/header.php');?>


<?php include('includes/menu.php');?>

<?php 
    include('includes/function.php');
    include('language/language.php');  

    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");    


    if(isset($_GET['directory_d_id']))
    {

        $img_res=mysql_query('SELECT * FROM tbl_directory WHERE d_id=\''.$_GET['directory_d_id'].'\'');
        $img_row=mysql_fetch_assoc($img_res);

            if($img_row['directory_image']!="")
            {
                unlink('images/'.$img_row['directory_image']);
                unlink('images/thumb/'.$img_row['directory_image']);

            }    

        Delete('tbl_directory','d_id='.$_GET['directory_d_id'].'');

        $_SESSION['msg']="18";
         header( "Location:manage_directory");
         exit;
    }

    //Active and Deactive status
    if(isset($_GET['status_deactive_id']))
    {
        $data = array('directory_status'  =>  '0');

        $edit_status=Update('tbl_directory', $data, "WHERE h_id = '".$_GET['status_deactive_id']."'");

         $_SESSION['msg']="12";
         header( "Location:manage_directory");
         exit;
    }
    if(isset($_GET['status_active_id']))
    {
        $data = array('directory_status'  =>  '1');

        $edit_status=Update('tbl_directory', $data, "WHERE h_id = '".$_GET['status_active_id']."'");

        $_SESSION['msg']="11";
         header( "Location:manage_directory");
         exit;
    }


    //Count Records
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM tbl_directory";
    $total_pages = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
    $total_pages = $total_pages['num'];


    $directory_qry="SELECT * FROM tbl_directory
                            LEFT JOIN tbl_category ON tbl_directory.d_cat_id= tbl_category.cid
                            LEFT JOIN tbl_sub_category ON tbl_directory.d_subcat_id= tbl_sub_category.sub_cat_id 
                         ORDER BY tbl_directory.d_id DESC";  

 $directory_result=mysql_query($directory_qry);

?>
<div class="content">

        <div class="header">

            <h1 class="page-title">Manage Listing</h1>
        </div>

            <ul class="breadcrumb">
            <li><a href="dashboard">Home</a> <span class="divider">/</span></li>
            <li class="active">Manage Listing</li>
         </ul>

         <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row-fluid">

<div class="btn-toolbar">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="window.location.href='add_directory?add'"><i class="icon-plus"></i> New Listing</button>

  <div class="btn-group">

  </div>
</div>
<div class="well">

<p style="color:#990000; font-size:14px;" align="center">
                    <?php if(isset($_SESSION['msg'])){ 
                        ?>

                    <div class="alert alert-info">
                         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
                         <?php echo $admin_lang[$_SESSION['msg']] ; ?>
                     </div>

                            <?php unset($_SESSION['msg']);      

                    }?>

</p>

<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script> 
      $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $('#directory_list').dataTable({                
                    "iDisplayLength":10,
                    "columnDefs": [
                        { "orderable": false, "targets": 4 },
                        { "orderable": false, "targets": 5 },
                        { "orderable": false, "targets": 6 },
                        { "orderable": false, "targets": 7 }
                    ]                
                <?php if($total_pages < 0){?>
                     ,"oLanguage": {
                    "sInfoEmpty": "No data available"
                    }                   
                    <?php }?>   
        }); 
      }); 



</script>


    <table id="directory_list"> 
        <thead> 
          <tr>             
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Category Name</th>
            <th>Sub Category Name</th>
            <th>Listing Name</th>
            <th>Image</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
          </tr> 
        </thead> 
        <tbody>
        <?php 
                    $i=1;
                    while($directory_row=mysql_fetch_array($directory_result))
                    {
                ?>

        <tr align="center">
          <td><?php echo $i;?></td>
          <td><?php echo $directory_row['category_name'];?></td>
          <td><?php echo $directory_row['sub_cat_name'];?></td>
          <td><?php echo $directory_row['directory_name'];?></td>   
          <td><img src="images/<?php echo $directory_row['directory_image'];?>" height="100" width="100" /></td>  

          <td>
                <?php if($directory_row['directory_status']!="0"){?>
              <a href="manage_directory?status_deactive_id=<?php echo $directory_row['h_id'];?>" title="Change Status"><i class="icon-plus"></i></a>
              <?php }else{?>
              <a href="manage_directory?status_active_id=<?php echo $directory_row['d_id'];?>" title="Change Status"><i class="icon-minus"></i></a>
              <?php }?>
          </td>     
          <td><a href="add_directory?directory_d_id=<?php echo $directory_row['d_id'];?>"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></a></td>

          <td>    <a href="#manage_directory<?php echo $directory_row['d_id'];?>" role="button" data-toggle="modal" title="Delete project"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a>

              <div class="modal small hide fade" id="manage_directory<?php echo $directory_row['d_id'];?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3 id="myModalLabel">Delete Confirmation</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p class="error-text"><i class="icon-warning-sign modal-icon"></i>Are you sure you want to delete this directorys?
</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="window.location.href='manage_directory?directory_d_id=<?php echo $directory_row['d_id'];?>'">Delete</button>
    </div>
</div>

           </td>

          </td>
        </tr>
       <?php $i++;}?>   
      </tbody>
      </table> 

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I misunderstood your question, you are asking how to modify multiple rows of the database at once.

```
$description = $_GET['description'];
$businesses = $_GET['businesses'];
mysql_query("UPDATE businesses SET description=$description WHERE name IN ($businesses);");
```

Where `$businesses` could be a result of something like this:

```
<input type="text" name="businesses" value="<?php print $current_business_being_examined_if_you_have_a_variable_like_this"><br />
<textarea name="description"><?php print $current_description_of_business;?></textarea>
```

And businesses is a comma separated list of names.

Comment: Yes. Exactly, I currently make changes to individual listing threw the admin panel, I just need to modify several listings at the same time.
For example. All businesses have name, phone number and description, want the option to select 5 businesses at the same time and lets say add a description of "open til 10pm" and have this text added to the 5 listings I chose without having to modify them individually.